# How to access nested NSDictionary in PLIST?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I have￼ nested `plist` file like this:
[image]

Which is the best way to access the strings in last dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *value = dictionary[@"STEP-1"][@"Step-2"][@"Step-3"][@"New item"];
```

**Swift**

```
let value = (((dictionary["STEP-1"] as? NSDictionary)?["Step-2"] as? NSDictionary)?["Step-3"] as? NSDictionary)?["New item"] as? String
```